# Guarding my methods against bad input

Tags: php, oop, validation, exception, null

I have a method like this:

```
public function create (array $hash) {
    $id = $hash[ID_KEY];
    $this->store[$id] = $hash;
}
```

I want to guard it against bugs caused by bad input.
For instance, my code can mistakenly pass `$hash` with

```
$id = '' or $id = null,
```

in which case it will be stored silently referenced by `null`. Instead I want to see a warning and revise my code to get rid of it. So I guess the best way is to throw Exception:

```
if (! $id) throw new Exception("Hash with empty id");
```

Note that I am using empty strings as default values for several method arguments and for default return values, so this kind of bug can easily occur. (Using `null` instead of empty string here doesn't seem to change anything, even if it is not recommended by Uncle Bob.)

The problem is -- there are many methods like that. Is it really best practice to guard **each** of them for **each** argument that can become `null` but shouldn't?

For instance, another method does only reading. Then it seems there is no need to guard against `null` because nothing will ever be stored referenced by `null`, right? Or shall I still guard defensively, to prepare for the case I may somewhere in the future decide to **allow** storage referenced by `null` and forget to adjust the guards?

This sounds kind of the safest way but would clutter all methods with bulks of guarding code for all indices involved there. Is this really the best way?

EDIT.
I put more guards and indeed discovered few bugs that I wouldn't find otherwise. Also my tests didn't spot them.

Furthermore, it helped to better understand the role of read methods - to return value if found *or* return `empty Array` if not. The input `$id = null` goes under *not found* and hence also returns `empty Array`. That way the method is clean and consistent.

Comment: It's up to you how careful you want to be. I don't think most programmers put lots of guards like this, they try to call their functions properly in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar I've tried exactly that and ended up painfully wasting way too much time hunting for bugs. :(

Comment: Then go ahead, put guards at the beginning of every function.

Comment: @Barmar It is not pretty but seems to be lesser evil. I've wrote a common purpose util function for that, so it is just one more line in each method.

Comment: Especially since this is tagged "oop": properly using objects can go a long way in reducing these kinds of problems. You'll have a few methods that will have to accepts scalar types and check them, but if you're handing around mostly properly type checked objects you'll have to do a lot less validation.

Comment: @deceze Indeed, I am only validating scalar types. Mainly these are string ids of hashes passed around. Maybe I should have wrapped each hash into object and pass around objects instead? Then I could enforce all the rules inside objects. Is this a common pattern?

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's [**is_null()**](http://www.php.net/is_null) and [**empty()**](http://www.php.net/manual/it/function.empty.php) to easily manage this kind of output.
Also I suggest you to write a list of function used only in debug (since you want to perfectionate your code). Call these function in each method you want to test and set a constant like **DEBUG_MODE** to handle the debug functions' behavior. All of this could be also done using [**unit testing**](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing), which would require more attention and time. But if you have both or want to learn something new, unit testing is clearly a better choice.

Also it is a good practice to handle ALL CASES you can think of. For instance, if your "reading method" expects not to find a null value (because you think there are none because you eradicated by testing over testing), if this "reading method" happens to find a null value a "ugly" PHP error would be shown somewhere, or worse, if error_report is shut you might never see a problem, or even worse, the code might continue its execution and utterly damage further data.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me more faith that I don't act like obsessive maniac putting all those guards. :) My read methods output empty strings to mark the end of the list, so if done badly, the receiver method will think the list is over and the data will be missed without any note. Pretty nasty. So I guess I'm stuck with the guards. Yes, I've been using tests and thought they basically replace the _debug mode_, I may be rethinking it though...

Comment: Concerning **debug mode** - my code is a cron daemon, so I suppose I should always keep it in _debug mode_ to see the errors.

Comment: Well, a switch bool variable is always advised, I thought you needed to debug your code only once in a while and then shut the "debug mode" down. For that purpose I'd say adding an header function to every function would be a bit excessive, and using exceptions would be rather quick and useful. Though you can combine both and have some functions which help you throwing exceptions (like I suggested in my answer). Also remind you can extend the basic [**Exceptions**](http://www.php.net/manual/it/language.exceptions.extending.php) to customize your code's behavior.