# I need this class to return a string value "error25" if it fails is it possible? - PHP

Tags: php

Hello everyone I have this class in php

```
<?php
namespace ExternalImporter\application\libs\pextractor\parser;

defined('\ABSPATH') || exit;
class Product {

    public $link;
    public $domain;
    public $title;
    public $description;
    public $price;
    public $currencyCode;
    public $image;
    public $oldPrice;
    public $manufacturer;
    public $inStock;
    public $availability;
    public $category;
    public $condition;
    public $ratingValue;
    public $reviewCount;
    public $features = array();
    public $images = array();
    public $reviews = array();
    public $paused;
    public $categoryPath = array();
    public $extra = array();

}
```

However when this is called with a null value it gives me a fatal error.
I need that when this error occurs it returns the result: `error25`

I call the class like this in a function

```
public static function update(Product $newProduct, $product_id)
{
//code
}
```

In this example, `$newProduct` has the value of NULL, which is why it would generate an error in the function.

If I can return the error string `error25` I could handle it.

Note: If the solution is to call the function, it is much better than editing the class itself.

**My goal is to achieve something like this**, but I'm not sure you can in PHP

```
public static function update(Product $newProduct ?: "error25", $product_id)
{
//code
}
```

Edit Possible solution

```
public static function update($newProduct, $product_id)
{
if (empty($newProduct)) {
# CALL Product $newProduct how to do it?
}
else {
$newProduct = NULL;
}
}
```

Comment: [`is_null()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) ?

Comment: Hello, Can you do it in an example please?

Comment: `if (is_null($yourVariable)) { /* do something */ }`

Comment: You are wanting a "guard clause" _inside_ the method signature?  How about validating the data prior to calling the method (a method which clearly states in its signature what data types are required)?  [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20593983/2943403)

Comment: @Cid It is not a solution since it would take me to edit many lines of code.
I am looking for a solution when calling the function or building the class.

Comment: @mickmackusa yes as 2nd option but the 1st option would be calling the function I put an example of what you want at the end of the question.

Comment: Very related to your previous question.  Have you abandoned [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73075325/2943403)?

Comment: Yes, a lot of issues as  mentioned above. Also, why will `update` be called with a null product value?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your error occurs not because of your parameter `$newProduct` is null and not an instance of `Product`. It occurs because you have logic in your method definition. You can 't do that.

```
public static function update(Product $newProduct ?: "error25", $product_id)
```

This should never work. It 's a syntax error. It results in: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected token "?", expecting ")"`. Please set your error reporting to the highest level, so that such basic errors are visible to you.

### Checking against null or instance of a class

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Marcel;

use Exception;
use stdClass;

class Foo
{
    public static function bar(?stdClass $yadda): void
    {
        if ($yadda === null) {
            throw new Exception('$yadda is not an instance of stdClass', 25);
        }
        // or ...
        if (!$yadda instanceof stdClass) {
            throw new Exception('$yadda is not an instance of stdClass', 25);
        }

        // everything okay at this point
        $yadda->someProperty = 'I am a valid stdClass instance';
    }
}
```

What happens here? Your static method takes a parameter that can either be an instance of `stdClass` or `null`. If `$yadda` is null an exception will be thrown with a message and a code.

### Catching type errors

With PHP 8 you can catch type errors. That 's another solution to your problem.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Marcel;

use stdClass;
use TypeError;

class Test
{
    public static function foo(stdClass $yadda): void
    {
        // some logic here
    }
}

try {
    Test::foo(null);
} catch (TypeErrror $error) {
    var_dump($error->getMessage());
    // Marcel\Test::foo(): Argument #1 ($bar) must be of type stdClass, null given
}
```

You can catch type errors in a try/catch block. If `$yadda` is something different than an instance of `stdClass` a type error will be thrown. You can handle this error in a catch block. With this solution you don 't have to declare your parameters as null or an instance of some class. You can just declare the type hint of a specific class and catch a type error when calling the static method.

Comment: I will study it however I want to ask if there is any way to do it by calling something like this from the function?
`public static function update(Product $newProduct ?: "error25", $product_id)
{
//code
}`

Comment: No, there is absolutely no way to define logic in your method definition. This always results in a syntax error.

Comment: Dear @Marcel
another solution would be to call the function like this and check if it is null
`public static function update($newProduct, $product_id) { //code }`

However, how could I call `Product $newProduct` inside the function?

Comment: Just use the null-operator in your parameter List. A definition like `?Product $product` says, that the given parameter `$product` can be null or an instance of Product. Check against null in your method logic. Just as shown above.

Comment: Dear @Marcel I edited the question but I have no idea how to call Product $newProduct inside the function

Comment: I try to understand but that makes no sense. You have defined a parameter list in your method definition. Just call `$newProduct` in your method body. It can be null or an instance of `Product`. If it 's null, just return your error code or throw an exeception. Easy as pie. All mentioned in the code example above. Try to understand it.

Comment: I happen to be a beginner in php. :(
My question is how to call the class from the function
but I don't know how to call it inside the function

Comment: Normally to call the class in the function I do this
`public static function update(Product $newProduct, $product_id)
{
//code
}`

Now I try to call the class inside the function doing this and it doesn't work.
`public static function update($newProduct, $product_id)
{
$myvar = Product $newProduct;
}`

Comment: If you want to make sure that your parameter is an instance of a certain class, just use [type hints](https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.declarations.php). I have edited my post and now also offered you a second possible solution to your problem. Please try to understand the solutions and implement them for yourself. It is very noticeable that you lack know-how in terms of PHP basics. Just try for yourself understanding how classes, methods, parameters, type hints and exceptions work. I have given you everything you need for this.